# How to use EMF commands within editor actions?

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

**Summary**
I am working on an emf-based editor. Up until now I didn't use EMF commands, but now I want to refactor my code to use them.

**Current state**
I am using a tree viewer as the main part of my editor. I added all kind of Actions via the   `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point. These actions directly interfere with the model, adding and removing objects.

**Problems**
With this approach I have to manually remove every reference when deleting objects in the model which easily introduces errors. Also the undo/redo actions in the editor don't work.

**Goal**
Refactor the Actions so they properly use EMF commands to modify the model.

---

Within the EMF documentation I found this code snippet:

```
  Department d = ...
  EditingDomain ed = ...
  Command cmd = RemoveCommand.create(ed, d);
  ed.getCommandStack().execute(cmd);
```

...which looks like the code I have to use. But I don't know where I can get the `EditingDomain` from.

So these are my questions:

- Is this the approach I want to use in my `Action`s?
- Where can I get the `EditingDomain` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to access the current editing domain. Just add this code to the `Action` class.

```
private EditingDomain domain;

public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart) {
    if (workbenchPart instanceof IEditingDomainProvider) {
        domain = ((IEditingDomainProvider) workbenchPart).getEditingDomain();
    }
}
```

The method `setActivePart` will automatically be called from the Eclipse framework. With this technique you should always have access to the editing domain.

Note that this is only true if your editor is based on mostly untouched generated code. If you manage the `EditingDomains` yourself you should use your own methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not already have an EditingDomain you can create one. However, it makes sense to create one globaly and keep it. For example inside a singleton.
Below you will find a minimal example deleting the EObject attached to a TreeItem using an AbstractCommand.

```
AdapterFactoryEditingDomain domain = new AdapterFactoryEditingDomain(new ComposedAdapterFactory(
        ComposedAdapterFactory.Descriptor.Registry.INSTANCE), new BasicCommandStack());

domain.getCommandStack().execute(new AbstractCommand() {
    @Override
    public void redo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        EcoreUtil.delete((EObject) treeItem.getData(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canExecute() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: With an emf-based editor the editing domain is normally already in play. It is used for all auto-generated standard commands like removing an object. Making a new editing domain would only add confusion.